# how to go deep into a tree with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm looking display categories tree. But I can't make the route in depth. unlimitedly, I am only using for loop.

I'm use nodejs, expressjs, mongoose then:

**Category model**

```js
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        select: true
    },
    _mother_category : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: false,
        select: true
    },})
```

So my for loop it's:

```js
// find mother cats
let mother_cat = await Category.find({ '_mother_category' : { $exists: false}}),
subcat;

// single deep
for (const mc of mother_cat) {
  subcat = await Category.find({ '_mother_category' : mc['_id'] })
            console.log(subcat['length'])  
}
```

But this wouldn't help me if I had more depth, and doing several for loops I don't think so either.

Any suggestion?

Rgds

Comment: while loop or recursion?  I hate recursion, personally though.

Comment: Well.... a while should be work.